# "Find in all Diagrams" as VB-Code

Tags: vbscript, enterprise-architect

I am trying to find one Element (in Enterprise Architect) in all diagrams in my model via VBScript.
Which command do I need for that operation?
How do I find all related Links of a Element?

Comment: I didn't find a command in the EA Help so far...
I could use a for-loop on all diagrams to get my "Find in all diagrams", but i don't know how to find its related links.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to get a list of all diagrams using an SQL query.
Use something like

```
select distinct d.diagram_ID from t_diagramobjects d
where d.Object_ID = [insert element id here]
```

Use this query with `Repository.SQLQuery()` to get a list of all DiagramIDs in xml format.

In order to get the data from the result you'll have to use a function similar to this one:

```
Public Function convertQueryResultToArray(xmlQueryResult)
    Dim arrayCreated
    Dim i 
    i = 0
    Dim j 
    j = 0
    Dim result()
    Dim xDoc 
    Set xDoc = CreateObject( "MSXML2.DOMDocument" )
    'load the resultset in the xml document
    If xDoc.LoadXML(xmlQueryResult) Then        
        'select the rows
        Dim rowList
        Set rowList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Row")

        Dim rowNode 
        Dim fieldNode
        arrayCreated = False
        'loop rows and find fields
        For Each rowNode In rowList
            j = 0
            If (rowNode.HasChildNodes) Then
                'redim array (only once)
                If Not arrayCreated Then
                    ReDim result(rowList.Length, rowNode.ChildNodes.Length)
                    arrayCreated = True
                End If
                For Each fieldNode In rowNode.ChildNodes
                    'write f
                    result(i, j) = fieldNode.Text
                    j = j + 1
                Next
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next
    end if
    convertQueryResultToArray = result
End Function
```

Once you have the diagramID's then you can use `Repository.GetDiagramByID()` to get the actual diagram.

Your original approach of looping ALL diagrams in the model will be hopelessly slow, even for small models.